# inverse triangle inequality in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I requiere some inequalities generalization. I don't know whether they are true or not. Can you help me ?

Here we're talking about $L^p$ spaces with $p > 1$.

> I know that on the real line :
>
> $$ ||x|-|y|| \leq | x-y | \leq |x|+|y| $$ equivalently :
>
> $$ ||x|-|y|| \leq | x+y | \leq |x|+|y|$$

Now i'm trying to find similar inequalities in Lebesgues spaces.

I already found that one :

$$(|x + y|)^p \leq 2^{p-1} (|x|^p + |y|^p)$$ thanks to Jensen ineqality.

I also know Minkowski inequality's telling me :

$$ \|f + g\|_{L^p} \leq \|f\|_{L^p} + \|g\|_{L^p}$$

> Now I'm searching for something on the other boundary. Meaning, as my
>   friends told me should be true :
>
> $$ |\|f\|_{L^p} - \|g\|_{L^p} | \leq  \|f-g\|_{L^p}$$ and
>   equivalently :
>
> $$ |\|f\|_{L^p} - \|g\|_{L^p} | \leq  \|f+g\|_{L^p}$$

i would also like to find something like this :

$$\lambda |(|x|^p - |y|^p)| \leq (|x + y|)^p $$

Do you know if something like those 2 inequalities exists, and if yes, how do you prove them ?

thanks !

Comment: It should probably "$\leq$" and not "$<$", shouldn't it?

Comment: isn't $\max\{|x|^p - |y|^p,|y|^p- |x|^p\} \leq |x+y|^p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result in the quote box is true by exactly the same proof as in $\mathbb R$.

The second part of your question is essentially a duplicate of this older question of mine, [Can I expect $|x|^s - |y|^s \leq C|x-y|^s$ for $s>1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678652/can-i-expect-xs-ys-leq-cx-ys-for-s1) (with related discussion) where a counterexample (valid already in dimension 1) shows that $||x|^p - |y|^p| \le C |x-y|^p$ is not possible for $p>1$. in 1D, the counterexample is obtained by choosing $$x=x_0,y=x_0 + t, \quad x_0 > 0,\quad  0<t\ll 1.$$

Essentially, this is because $|x|^p$ is $C^1$ when $p>1$ so we have the (local) estimate from Mean Value Theorem,
$$  |x+h|^p - |x|^p  \approx   p\operatorname{sgn}(x)|x|^{p-1} h.$$
That is, the leading error term is linear in $h$, and its not possible to obtain a bound with a higher order error term than $|h|$.

Answer (score 6):

In any normed space $$||x||=||(x-y)+y||\le||x-y||+||y||,$$hence $$||x||-||y||\le||x-y||.$$Similarly (or "hence, swapping $x$ and $y$"), $$||y||-||x||\le||x-y||.$$ If $a,b\in\Bbb R$ then $|a-b|=\max(a-b,b-a)$, so 
$$\big|\,||x||-||y||\,\big|\le||x-y||.$$

Comment: could you please also take a look at the other part, which is related to what you said in a way ? or do you agree with our fellow @Calvin Khor ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin Looks like the other answer takes care of the other  part...

Comment: yeah ok i agree with you. I just don't know to whom give the ok answer. I already upvoted the other post, so i think since you did the major part of the answer you deserve the most.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Don't worry about that, accept whichever you like. If you can't  decide, note he could use the points more  than me...

Comment: If instead of looking at the norm $$  || \cdot ||_{L^p} $$ we look at  $$  || \cdot ||_{L^p}^p $$ you agree that the inequalities we talked about aren't true anymore if you try to for instance just distribute the power ? For instance, simply, the Minkowski inequality won't be true? And you can't majorate an expression like : 
$$ ||f||_{L^p}^p - ||g||_{L^p}^p  $$
as I wanted, because of Calvin's reference ? The best you could do it taking the exponents on both side of the inequation? which would give
$$ ( \big|\, ||f||_{L^p} - ||g||_{L^p}  \,\big| )^p  \le||f-g||_{L^p}^p $$

Comment: @MarineGalantin Right - Calvin's reference shows it fails for the $p$th power of the norm.