# $\int \bigg||f|^p-|g|^p\bigg|d\mu\leq \int \big|f-g\big|^pd\mu$ , for $ 0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, proof-verification, integral-inequality

Prove that
$$\int \bigg||f|^p-|g|^p\bigg|d\mu\leq \int \big|f-g\big|^pd\mu$$

for all $f, g \in L^p([0, 1]; \mu)$ and $0 < p < 1$.

Is the following correct?

the function $f(t)=|t|^p$ , $0 < p < 1$ is concave.  So $\forall \alpha \in (0,1)$;

$$ |x-y|^p = |\alpha\frac{x}{\alpha}-(1-\alpha)\frac{y}{1-\alpha}|^p \geq \alpha|\frac{x}{\alpha}|^p+(1-\alpha)|\frac{y}{1-\alpha}|^p$$

let $\alpha = \frac{|x|}{|x|+|y|}$ and $1-\alpha = \frac{|y|}{|x|+|y|}$
\begin{align}
|x-y|^p 
& \geq \alpha\frac{|x|^p}{ \frac{|x|^p}{(|x|+|y|)^p}}+(1-\alpha)\frac{|y|^p}{ \frac{|y|^p}{(|x|+|y|)^p}}\\
& = \alpha(|x|+|y|)^p+(1-\alpha)(|x|+|y|)^p\\
& = (|x|+|y|)^p\\
& \geq |x|^p+|y|^p\\
& \geq \bigg||x|^p-|y|^p\bigg|\\
\end{align}

so taking integration 
$$|f-g|^p \geq \bigg||f|^p-|g|^p\bigg|$$
$$\int|f-g|^pd\mu \geq \int\bigg||f|^p-|g|^p\bigg|d\mu$$

Comment: If $x = y \neq 0$ it seems that you have derived $2|x|^p \le 0$

Comment: You need to somehow use the fact that $x=0\implies |x|^p = 0$, I think the result isn't true for general concave functions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295551/concave-implies-subadditive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its enough to prove the identity for numbers $a,b\ge 0$,
$$ |a+b|^p + \le |a|^p + |b|^p$$

We use the idea from [Concave implies subadditive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295551/concave-implies-subadditive).

Note that $a = \alpha (a+b)$, $b = (1-\alpha)(a+b)$, where $\alpha = \frac{a}{a+b}$. Then the right hand side is
$$ |\alpha (a+b) + (1-\alpha) 0 |^p +  |(1-\alpha) (a+b) + \alpha 0 |^p \ge \alpha|a+b|^p + (1-\alpha)|a+b|^p = |a+b|^p. $$

Comment: Do you remember how to prove the equivalent for $p=1$? Its 100% exactly the same

Comment: then if I take $a = f-g$ and $b=g$ It would be $|f-g+g|^p \le |f-g|^p + |g|^p \implies |f|^p - |g|^p \le |f-g|^p $ , what is the role of $0<p<1$ is this proof?

Comment: @stat_yale In the earlier part. For concavity. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678652/can-i-expect-xs-ys-leq-cx-ys-for-s1?noredirect=1&lq=1 see here, result is false for $p>1$

Comment: In above I can write using that the function$ f(t)=|t|^p , 0<p<1$ is concave. So $\forall \alpha\in(0,1)$; $$ |x+y|^p = |\alpha\frac{x}{\alpha}+(1-\alpha)\frac{y}{1-\alpha}|^p \geq \alpha|\frac{x}{\alpha}|^p+(1-\alpha)|\frac{y}{1-\alpha}|^p$$
let $\alpha = \frac{|x|}{|x|+|y|}$ and $1-\alpha = \frac{|y|}{|x|+|y|}$
\begin{align}
|x+y|^p 
& \geq \alpha\frac{|x|^p}{ \frac{|x|^p}{(|x|+|y|)^p}}+(1-\alpha)\frac{|y|^p}{ \frac{|y|^p}{(|x|+|y|)^p}}\\
& = \alpha(|x|+|y|)^p+(1-\alpha)(|x|+|y|)^p\\
& = (|x|+|y|)^p\\
& \geq |x|^p+|y|^p\\
\end{align}

which is the opposite. What is wrong here?

Comment: @stat_yale take $y=-x$

Comment: @stat_yale maybe I should say more. $|t|^p$ is concave $\color{red}{\text{ for  }t>0}$.

Comment: Right, I got the counter example. Just wondering which step in above is not correct.

Comment: the very first step, application of concavity failed