# Does this Peetre inequality variant have its own name?

Tags: inequality, reference-request

I'm wondering if the following 'additive' Peetre's inequality has its own name?

> for $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$, $p\ge 0$, and $c=\max(2^p,2^{2p-1})$, $$|1+|x|^2|^p \leq c \big((1+|x-y|^2)^p + (1+|y|^2)^p\big)$$

If not a name, then a reference where someone uses it will do...

I just recently found out that  [Peetre's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peetre%27s_inequality) is instead usually the following 'multiplicative' inequality, valid for all $s\in\mathbb R$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$:

\begin{equation}
(1 + |x + y|^2)^s \leq 2^{|s|}(1 + |x|^2)^s(1 + |y|^2)^{|s|} 
\end{equation}
There's also this related inequality [Showing the inequality $|\alpha + \beta|^p \leq 2^{p-1}(|\alpha|^p + |\beta|^p)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143173/showing-the-inequality-alpha-betap-leq-2p-1-alphap-betap?rq=1) .

I'll end the question with a proof of the boxed inequality just in case someone is worried.

> For $p>1/2$, the function $\phi(x)=|1+|x|^2|^p$ is convex. Thus $\phi(x/2) \le \frac{\phi(y)}2 + \frac{\phi(x-y)}2$, i.e.
>   $$ |1+|x/2|^2|^p \leq \frac12 \big((1+|x-y|^2)^p + (1+|y|^2)^p\big)$$
>   Multiplying by $2^{2p}$ we obtain
>   $$ |4+|x|^2|^p \leq 2^{2p-1} \big((1+|x-y|^2)^p + (1+|y|^2)^p\big),$$
>   which is clearly enough. For $p<1$, instead use the convexity of $1+|x|^2$, getting
>   $$4 +|x|^2 \le 2 (1+|y|^2) + 2(1+|x-y|^2),$$
>   and then the [subadditivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295551/concave-implies-subadditive) of $|\cdot|^p$ for $p<1$ finishes the proof.