# Concavity, Uniform Boundedness

Tags: convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Can someone explain the inequality? What property of concave functions is this using?[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I am the downvoter. The reasons are in Martin's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-negative concave functions are [subadditive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity), see for example [Concave implies subadditive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295551/42969):
$$
 f(t+\tau) \le f(t) + f(\tau) \, .
$$
For the estimate in the other direction use that $g(t) = f(1-t)$ is also concave:
$$
 f(t) = g(1-t) \le g(1-t-\tau) + g(\tau) = f(t+\tau) + f(1-\tau) \, .
$$